# Creating facets for ggplot boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet

I have a dataframe set up as follows:

| Region | Sub-region | March | April | May |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A1 | 9.2 | 7.9 | 8.0 |
| A | A2 | 8.9 | 8.5 | 8.0 |
| A | A3 | 9.5 | 8.5 | 8.4 |
| B | B1 | 9.1 | 8.7 | 8.5 |
| B | B2 | 9.9 | 8.0 | 7.7 |
| C | C1 | 8.7 | 8.0 | 8.2 |
| C | C2 | 9.3 | 8.0 | 8.4 |
| C | C3 | 9.1 | 8.3 | 8.5 |

I've melted the dataframe so its in this format:

| Region | Sub-region | Variable | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I'm trying to create a ggplot boxplot with a facet wrap/grid so that the output contains a panel for each region and within each panel is a boxplot for each sub-region. I've tried the below code but it's not the desired output:

```
p<- Name_SR %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, sub_region)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(title="",
       subtitle ="
         ",
       x="Percentage Difference", 
       y = "Sub-Region") + 
  facet_wrap(~Region) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.margin=unit(c(1,6,1,1),"cm"),
        plot.title = element_text(size=12), 
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size=10),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 10))
q<- p + theme(axis.text = element_text(size=8))
```

Would someone be able to help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do what you are looking for, if `Name_SR` is your melted df...

```
Name_SR %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = sub_region, y = value)) +  #yours are the wrong way round
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~Region, scales = "free_x")    #free_x removes irrelevant subregions
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! Sorry, I should of mentioned the name of the melted df!